# Ionic2 customizing the toolbar in side-menu app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an Ionic 2 application with side-menu and want to customize my side menu as can be seen in the following image (*not exact same, however the important part is how to get that first block with such a picture and some text*), with custom color for the entire toolbar etc?:

[image]

My application looks like following:

[image]

**My app.html:**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        <ion-icon name="{{p.name}}"></ion-icon>
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just adding some standard HTML code, and with CSS you can customize the style. Create the `CSS Class rules` in the .scss file. Rember to import 
`@import "build/app.html";` in the app.core.scss file. You'll find other information to personalize your app [there](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/)

And for display the first block part you can add your code before the `ion-list` of the menu and after the tag `<ion-content>`.

You can delete this part, so it's more easy to create your custom layout. 
`<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>`

The code will be:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-content>
      <!--Here you can add all the code 
      you want, so you can display whatever you want-->

     <!--Menu list--> 
    <ion-list class="menuList">
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" class="menuButton">
        <ion-icon name="{{p.name}}"></ion-icon>
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

If you need some more help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Can you kindly provide any such HTML with css if you have any?

Comment: that answer is perfect . No one will give u exact css . Do one thing use  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="../assets/side_icon.png">
        <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
        <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
      </div>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>  before <ion-content > and write down ur own css